# Putting a Copy of an Object into A Collection

Tags: vba, object, collections

I have a loop which runs over 100,000 times where I read a text file which gives my information to create Service objects.

For searching later on, I need to put these Service objects into a collection (with defined keys).

The problem I'm facing is that I have a this_service variable (Service object) which I add at the end of the loop to the all_services collection - but since the `add` method is by reference, I end up having a collection with 100,000 duplicates of the final object I create.

Is there no way that I can add the custom object to the collection ByVal?

Comment: In a word, no. Reference types are reference types, full stop. If you pass them `ByVal` it only means that you can't reassign the *reference*.

Comment: @Comintern is there no way that I can take a copy though? Instead of passing the pointer?

Comment: To take a copy, you will have to  create a new object based on the members of the old one.